# Selenium IE Webdriver - NoSuchWindowException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been breaking my head for hours over this exception that I Keep getting. I'm fresh to python & selenium so I might have overlooked something.
Either way, the goal is to automate data entry into a website by reading it from a csv. But as soon as i log in, and want to find an element on that page, i get the exception, and i can't find the answer anywhere, got no clue at all. Everything seems to be configured correctly.

Do I need to somehow refresh the URL of the driver? Is it possible that an 'on website' pop up is resposible for this?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUcUW.jpg) (see image) Do note that this webinterface we use only works on IE, so, i can't switch to a different browser and try it over there.

```
import time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def workflow(Operation_Type, fInput):

    UNCRM = input("Please Enter CRM Username: ")
    PWCRM = input("Please Enter CRM Password: ")
    driver = LoginCRM(UNCRM,PWCRM)
    ImportISSI(fInput, driver)

def LoginCRM(UNCRM,PWCRM):

    opts = Options()
    opts.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True
    opts.ignore_zoom_level = True
    opts.require_window_focus = False
    driver = webdriver.Ie(ie_options=opts)
    driver.get("URL")
    UnLoginCRM = driver.find_element_by_name("txtUserName")
    PwLoginCRM = driver.find_element_by_name("txtPassword")
    UnLoginCRM.send_keys(UNCRM)
    PwLoginCRM.send_keys(PWCRM)
    PwLoginCRM.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
    return driver

def ImportISSI(fName, driver):
    # Imports the ISSI from a .CSV to recover
    
    fName = r"Path\{}".format(fName)
    with open(fName, mode='r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        line_count = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            if line_count == 0:
                line_count += 1
            line_count = RecoverCRM(row["ISSI"],row["TEI"],row["Reference Number"],line_count, driver)
        print(f'Processed {line_count} ISSI.')

def RecoverCRM(ISSI, TEI, Ref, line_count, driver):
    # uses the ISSI to search for on CRM
    # then follows the controls to recover the radio
    
    print("\t{} Is linked with TEI {} According to the End User as per request {} for recovery.".format(ISSI, TEI, Ref))

    WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"txtAccountNoAccessNo")))
    QuickSearch = driver.find_element_by_name("txtAccountNoAccessNo")
    QuickSearch.send_keys(ISSI)
    QuickSearch.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(15)
    line_count += 1


    return line_count

def Bypass(UN,PW,fInput):
     driver = LoginCRM(UN,PW)
     ImportISSI(fInput, driver)
```

Comment: Hey, If the popup has a close button just use a webdriver wait to target that element and use .click() on it.As well as using waits on your login elements to make it more stable.

Comment: use `try/except` to catch error and run rest of code.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan the pop up seems to be embedded in the webpage, either way, i've tried that, but the same error occurs. I've tried to do it with a different webapp as well (because this one is only available for IE) and that webapp works using both chrome and ie, so the issue is with this website only.

Comment: @furas, from the point at which i'm logged into the site, any further code that tries to interact with the site causes the same error regardless of what I do. Might just be unfortunate IE weirdness?

Comment: you could test it with Chrome/Firefox to confirm it